# Error with Excel IF formatting, My function isn't working

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to create an excel conditional IF function using Microsoft EXCEL 2010.

It's reading the function correctly, but instead of calculating, it's just returning the formula.

Here is the function.

```
=IF(B2>199,"(A2/B2)/.015",IF(B2<199,"=(A2/B2)/.07"))
```

When the value is greater than 199 it returns (A2/B2)/.015 instead of the answer.

When the value is less than 199 then it returns =(A2/B2)/.07 instead of the answer.

the A2 and B2 cells are set as currency but I've also tried it as general and as a number.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `"` around calculation:
`=IF(B2>199,(A2/B2)/0.015,IF(B2<199,(A2/B2)/0.07))`